# Is it possible to let users locate all stores along route?

Tags: php, json, html, csv

I would like to let users use Google Maps in my store application to find all of my stores along a specified route.

This is the flow I envision:

1. User creates a starting point and an endpoint for a trip.
2. User selects a distance from the route that they would be comfortable traveling to get to one of our stores.  This would be  in miles, say, from 1 to 50 miles.
3. Given those parameters, Google Maps displays the route along with markers for all stores within those parameters.
4. User then can click on the stores they want to visit while driving to the destination.
5. When they are done, my program will generate a list of all the stores they have selected along their route.

A couple of notes:

I have a database of all of our stores that includes city, state, zip, lat, long.  It can also contain all of the info that I want returned to the user when the list of stores are selected on the route such as hours, services, etc.

I just need to know if this functionality is possible within the Google Maps api.

Comment: It would probably be theoretically possible -- you would need to broaden the 'width' of the journey so that it isn't just a line down a street, but rather a rectangle (or similar shape) *containing* the stores. Then you would just list every store contained within that area.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear.  Let's say I'm travelling 500 miles.  Most of our stores are located within 25 miles of interstates.  What I'm looking for is to allow our customers to enter their starting city and their ending city and have the application show all of our stores that are located within X miles of the route google computes.  So say they're travelling from Los Angeles to Portland, it would list all stores within X miles of I5 between the two cities.  I'm thinking RouteBoxes would be the best way to do this.  Just wondering if this is an application of the utility that would work.